# Вывод строки в TextBox с сохранением переносов

Tags: c#, winforms

Никак не могу добиться вывода в строки в текстбокс (или мемоэдит, или текстэдит, тоже) в том виде, в котором строка есть.
Пример, так выглядит строка, если смотреть в дебаге
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а после вставки в тексбокс  строка выглядит в нём сплошным текстом, с пробелами. а мне нужно чтобы также красиво, с отступами

строка получается так:

```
 public static string GetStringFromWeb(string link)
    {
        string src = string.Empty;
        int try_cnt = 0;
        HttpWebRequest request = null;
        while (try_cnt < 2)
        {
            try
            {
                request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(link);
                request.Timeout = 1000;
                using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
                using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    src = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
            catch
            { }
            try_cnt++;
        }
        return src;
    }
```

Comment: Нужно создать метод-расширение, либо что-то подобное для строки, где посимвольно разбирать строку, если встрчается [ { - вставляем новую строку (Environment.NewLine), и т.д.

Comment: А вы текстбоксу то сделали multiline? А также стоит уточнить что вы используете (WPF/WinForms). Ибо все мои попытки засунуть отформатированный json в TextBox привели к успешным результатам! Вот к примеру, я [создаю](https://hastebin.com/iweyejoboc.cs) тестовые данные и заношу в свойство, далее делаю обычный, multiline TextBox ( `<TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" Text="{Binding Text}"/>` ) и получаю нужный [результат](https://imgur.com/a/q1vWEsC). Так что давайте-ка нам побольше информации и ваши попытки...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ multiline есть, использую winforms. строку получаю так

Comment: Значит ваш JSON изначально не имеет форматирования. Советую вам использовать библиотеку JSON.NET и перед вводом в TextBox сделать что то вроде этого: `JToken.Parse(GetStringFromWeb("...")).ToString(Formatting.Indented);`;

Comment: Если задача — сделать из строки без отступов строку с отступами, то вообще не стоит говорить о текстбокс, т.к. нет разницы где выводить строку. Лучше строку привести целиком прямо в коде (сократив до разумного), ведь то, как она формируется, тоже к делу не относится. И наоборот, если вопрос про то как строку X показать в текстбоксе, то нужно привести пример именно с текстбоксом.

Answer (score 3):

```
  JToken parsedJson = JToken.Parse(JSON);
            var beautified = parsedJson.ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
```